# JavaFX Freehand Smoothing Algorithm

Tags: java, javafx, drawing, smoothing

I am looking to integrate a high quality, anti-aliased freehand draw feature, such as the one described here: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/smoother-signatures-be64515adb33.

Using the canvas in JavaFX, I seem to have reached a dead end on how to perform a smoothing operation. I tried using bezier curves every 4th point, but the mouseDragged event occurs on such tiny intervals that this is not practical nor useful.

I've taken a look at the Akima algorithm (described here:  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/interpolation/AkimaSplineInterpolator.html ), but I am not quite sure how I would go from a polynomial to a canvas, or how the algorithm would respond to inputs that are not functions (i.e. 2 y-values for a particular x value).

So far, I have been using a pretty simple     strokeLine     method for freehand drawing

Here is a screenshot of the aliased figure I am trying to correct https://i.ibb.co/1J49z0W/Capture.png

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).